# Multi-tenant app with custom domains: how to populate tenant specific data in initializers and mailers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, multi-tenant

I'm creating a multi-tenant app which uses Devise for authentication, which has an initializer file to set app specific information.

I'd also like to use the tenant's domain information in mailers.

What's the best way to store this information and populate it in the initializers and mailers?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have tenant specific information including mailer information in file. Natural thing is to store information in database table. If you properly setup multi-tenant app, then database data for each tenant is completely separate from other tenants.

For example you could have table **TenantInformation** and put all tenant specific information like mailer connection string inside. 
And depending of Rails verision you can set mailer connection option dinamicaly before sending email with **:delivery_method_options** check:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

You can use existing solutions like https://github.com/influitive/apartment for easier work with tenants.

Comment: My issue is with initializers. I already put tenant specific information in the DB, but how can I set it in initializers (which is required for gems like Devise, etc).

Comment: Can you be more specific please, what initializer exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could come up with to properly include tenant subdomains in mailers and view links/urls is to monkey-patch `url_for`(which is internally used by other url helpers):

```
module ActionDispatch::Routing
  class RouteSet

    alias_method :original_url_for, :url_for
    def url_for(options, route_name = nil, url_strategy = UNKNOWN)
      dynamic_options = Rails.application.config.respond_to?(:dynamic_url_options) ? Rails.application.config.dynamic_url_options.call : {}
      options = options.merge(default_url_options).merge(dynamic_options)

      original_url_for options, route_name, url_strategy
    end
  end
end
```

Put this in `lib/dynamic_url_options.rb`, then `require 'dynamic_url_options'` at the top of your environment file.  You can then do:

```
config.dynamic_url_options = lambda {{
  :subdomain => Apartment::Tenant.current
}}
```

If you're prefixing your tenant names with your environment, you'll have to do some additional stripping of the `staging_` prefix within this lambda.